# Evaluating classifiers based on aggregated confidence scores

Tags: math, machine-learning, statistics

We have a "trained classifier". This is not necessarily a classifier such as a SVM, MLP etc.

The classifier returns a list of outputs evaluated with a confidence score.

**Given an input, the output could look like this:**

- Matched output 1 -> score 90
- Matched output 2 -> score 85
- Matched output 3 -> score 80

In this case we would consider the classifier result to be "bad", since the **distance** of all confidence scores for all outputs is "low".

**Given a different input, the output could look like this:**

- Matched output 1 -> score 90
- Matched output 2 -> score 45
- Matched output 3 -> score 25

In this case we would consider the classifier result to be "good", since the **distance** of all confidence scores for all outputs is "high".

We have a lot of inputs that we can run through the system.

Is there a way to find out what is the "high enough" **distance** so that I can say the model is "confident enough"?

This is not meant for comparing algorithms, but the systems performance to itself over time.

Comment: I doubt there is a rule that is universal i.e. works for any set of classifiers and any data. You should experiment with your particular case and set thresholds specific for your task. P.S. In some way this is a meta-classification task: you are trying to classify scores into ones that you are sure about the answer and the ones you don't.

Comment: Question is more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com.